# Silverlight vs W8/W8.1/WP8/WP8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I know you can develop W8 apps using c# and XAML. Is it the same on wp8 ?

How does Silverlight relate to all of this and how does WP8.1/WP8 relate to all of this.

Please tell me if you want more specifics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can develop apps on Windows Phone using C# and XAML.

Windows 8 uses a runtime called WinRT. Windows Phone traditionally uses a runtime called Silverlight. Both are on based on C# and XAML, but they have different controls and different classes.

Starting with Windows Phone 8.1, you can make phone apps using WinRT. So you can now write apps for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 using the same runtime (and therefore share large portions of the code): they are called "Universal Apps".

As to know which one you should use:

- If you want to make an app for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone then it's a no-brainer: create an universal app
- If you want to make an app that will run only on Windows Phone, then I would personally recommand using WinRT since that's the "future-proof" choice. However, some Windows Phone APIs aren't supported yet by the WinRT runtime. If you need one of those APIs, then you have no choice but using Silverlight.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eob/archive/2014/04/16/starting-with-universal-apps-on-visual-studio-2013.aspx

> On this version we have a API convergence of 90%, still there is a small set not converget yet, that are Phone features only available in Silverlight such:
>
> - Lenses Support
> - VOIP Suport
> - Camera Capture Task
> - Clipboard APIs
> - Lock Screen Wallpaper API

Answer (score 3):

1 Ans: You can develop `Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 7, Windows Phone 8 & Windows Phone 8.1` applications using `C# & XAML`.

2: Ans: Windows Phone 7, Windows Phone 8 & Windows Phone 8.1 (Targetting Silverlight) uses `Silverlight API's`. And how Windows Phone 8 & Windows Phone 8.1 relate to Silverlight, well they use the SIlverlight API's that are available for mobile application framework.

Windows 8 & Windows 8.1 both target `WinRT API's`. Currently Windows Phone 8.1 also support WinRT API's. So, if you want to create Windows 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1 applications that you can do by creating a `Universal application` targeting both the platforms (They have convergence of 90%).

```
If you want to create Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8 applications, you will require Visual Studio 2012 & Windows 8 OS.
If you want to create Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8 & Windows Phone 8.1 applications , you require Visual Studio 2013 & Windows 8.1 OS.
```

This [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714089%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) gives you a brief idea about Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8 app development.

Hope this helps.